# SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' on IE ~ Vue.js ~ MDBootstrap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, mdbootstrap

I have a simple Vue.js application which works perfectly on other browsers than IE, which shows a blank page with an error `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'`. I have added a `vue.config.js` file which looks like that:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["bootstrap-css-only", "mdbvue"]
};
```

My `.babelrc` file is a default one taken from the official project [starting page](https://mdbootstrap.com/education/vue/getting-started/), this is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

In my `main.js` file I tried 2 approaches:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

and

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
```

Both didn't change anything and the error and behaviour is the same. The only one thing which still comes to my mind to solve this problem is mentioned [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/ie11-vue-cli-webpack-babel-script1003-error/16257/6), i.e. in `export default` I'm using the following syntax for component:

```
components: {
  mdbContainer,
  mdbRow,
  mdbCol,
  mdbCard,
  mdbCardBody,
  mdbInput,
  mdbBtn,
  mdbIcon,
  mdbModalFooter,
  mdbView
}
```

Edit2: But if I'll drop this lines then all my UI elements from MDBootstrap are gone. Is there any other way to use it? I wanted simply to use polyfills.

I tried to create `babel.config.js` file, but also didn't help. The logic in this file is like that:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@vue/app", { useBuiltIns: "entry" }]]
};
```

Is there anything I'm missing? What I understood the `vue.config.js` file doesn't has to be imported anywhere, because [*`vue.config.js` is an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by `@vue/cli-service`*](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js). Here are my questions:

1. Any ideas what can be wrong?
2. Shall I have `babel.config.js` **and** `.babelrc` or only one of these?
3. Is `babel.config.js` file automatically detected like `vue.config.js`?
4. [Edit] Maybe something in webpack configuration should be changed?

Vue CLI version:

```
$ vue --version
3.11.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I recreated the project using `vue-cli 4` and left all the defaults alone.I did not reference `babel` or `core-js` in my `main.js`. I looked at the console error in IE to see which library was causing the script error,( lets call it `some-imported-lib` ). Then I added that library in `vue.config.js` as follows

```
transpileDependencies:['some-imported-lib']
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem! Basically, needed only to upgrade to Vue CLI 4 (had 3) and that's all! The MDBootstrap also upgrade 12 days ago to the newest CLI and apparently this issue no longer exists =)

Comment: PS. The `vue.config.js` was not needed even.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that IE11 doesn't support shorthand property notation, but you're using that in your `components` list. Your `.babelrc` isn't set to ensure that the resulting code can run on IE11.

You'll want to review [the browserlist documentation](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) to fine-tune your `browsers` setting, but for instance adding `IE 11` to it will ensure that the transpiled code has all the transforms required to run on IE11.

Note that IE11 basically doesn't support anything in ES2015+. (It has `const` and a broken version of `let`, but that's basically it.) So doing this will effectively transpile all your code to ES5 levels. You may want to serve different bundles to IE and to other, more modern browsers.

Comment: I tried to change the element of the list from `browsers`, i.e. `"not ie <= 8"` to `"ie 10"` as well as `"ie 11"` and the same error. The IE I'm testing on is IE11. Are there any meta tags required in the `index.html` or it can be related with intranet using in my company?

Comment: @DanielDanielecki - Not for this specific problem, no, though I always suggest including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` and turning off intranet mode anyway.

Comment: @DanielDanielecki - Are you sure you're sending the transpiled result to the browser rather than the untranspiled version? Because [Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/REPL#?babili=false&browsers=>%201%25%2C%20last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20<%3D%208&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAjAGhgIyTATAbgChRJYRMArHAbzg0wF98g&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env) transpiles the shorthand with that browser list.

Comment: @t.j-crowder I'd expect the shorthand is quite common thing so it'll be transpired. I'm simply running `npm run dev` and checking this on localhost. Is something wrong with this approach? Quite new to Vue.js, coming from an Angular world - just in case if it would be really basic question. I had the meta tag already, was thinking maybe anything else there could be. Simply trying any way.